# Filtering date ranges by special condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, intervals, date-range

I have a table with the following data (sorted by StartDate):

```
    | Id | StartDate           | EndDate             |
    |----|---------------------|---------------------|
    | 1  | 2017-03-18 00:00:00 | 2017-03-18 02:00:00 |
    | 2  | 2017-03-18 01:30:00 | 2017-03-18 04:00:00 |
    | 3  | 2017-03-18 01:45:00 | 2017-03-18 03:00:00 |
    | 4  | 2017-03-18 02:10:00 | 2017-03-18 02:30:00 |
    | 5  | 2017-03-18 02:35:00 | 2017-03-18 02:50:00 |
    | 6  | 2017-03-18 03:20:00 | 2017-03-18 03:50:00 |
    | 7  | 2017-03-18 05:00:00 | 2017-03-18 05:30:00 |
    | 8  | 2017-03-18 05:10:00 | 2017-03-18 07:00:00 |
    | 9  | 2017-03-18 05:50:00 | 2017-03-18 08:00:00 |
```

Filtration logic:
After the first period of dates, we find another with which it does not intersect.
Then the logic is repeated with respect to the found period.

After filtering should remain:

```
    | Id | StartDate           | EndDate             |
    |----|---------------------|---------------------|
    | 1  | 2017-03-18 00:00:00 | 2017-03-18 02:00:00 |
    | 4  | 2017-03-18 02:10:00 | 2017-03-18 02:30:00 |
    | 5  | 2017-03-18 02:35:00 | 2017-03-18 02:50:00 |
    | 6  | 2017-03-18 03:20:00 | 2017-03-18 03:50:00 |
    | 7  | 2017-03-18 05:00:00 | 2017-03-18 05:30:00 |
    | 9  | 2017-03-18 05:50:00 | 2017-03-18 08:00:00 |
```

Is it possible to implement this without using the CURSOR?

For convenient use of records:

```
CREATE TABLE #Dates (Id INT, StartDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME);
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 1, '2017-03-18 00:00:00', '2017-03-18 02:00:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 2, '2017-03-18 01:30:00', '2017-03-18 04:00:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 3, '2017-03-18 01:45:00', '2017-03-18 03:00:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 4, '2017-03-18 02:10:00', '2017-03-18 02:30:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 5, '2017-03-18 02:35:00', '2017-03-18 02:50:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 6, '2017-03-18 03:20:00', '2017-03-18 03:50:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 7, '2017-03-18 05:00:00', '2017-03-18 05:30:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 8, '2017-03-18 05:10:00', '2017-03-18 07:00:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 9, '2017-03-18 05:50:00', '2017-03-18 08:00:00';
DROP TABLE #Dates;
```

Comment: what is the version of sql-server you are using?

Comment: I use MSSQL Server 2014

Comment: you can use `LAG` function to achieve this , check my answer for more details

Comment: @IvanAntonov Thank you for putting in sample data - makes it easier on everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution found:**

```
WITH PIP AS (
    SELECT [D1].*, [T].*
    FROM #Dates [D1]
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 Id AS NextId FROM #Dates [D2]
        WHERE 
            NOT ([D1].StartDate <= [D2].EndDate AND [D1].EndDate >= [D2].StartDate) AND [D2].Id > [D1].Id
        ORDER BY [D2].StartDate
    ) AS [T]
), POP AS (
    SELECT [T].Id, [T].StartDate, [T].EndDate, [T].NextId
        FROM PIP [T]
    WHERE [T].Id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [X].Id, [X].StartDate, [X].EndDate, [X].NextId
        FROM PIP [X]
    JOIN POP [H] ON [H].NextId = [X].Id
)
SELECT * FROM POP;
```

Comment: Great job. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this without a cursor.  Here is a version using `exists`, assuming no exact duplicates on start date:

```
select min(id), min(startdate), max(startdate)
from (select t.*, sum(flag) over (order by startdate) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when not exists (select 1
                                          from t t2
                                          where t2.startdate < t.startdate and
                                                t2.enddate >= t.startdate
                                         )
                         then 1 else 0
                    end) as flag
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
group by grp;
```

The innermost subquery calculates a flag to determine if rows overlap.  The middle level accumulates this flag to identify each group, and the outer one does the aggregation.

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong to describe the essence of the problem.
For the time being, a non-existent solution should output records that are in the second table. But, this solution does not work correctly, and I do not see the possibility of fixing it :(.

Comment: @IvanAntonov . . . I think the problem is merely that the `not exists` was looking for any overlap in the time frame.  However, the flag needs to be set only when the overlap is on `starttime`.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with SQL Server 2012, you can use [LEAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) And [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) function to achieve this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Dates (Id INT, StartDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME);
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 1, '2017-03-18 00:00:00', '2017-03-18 02:00:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 2, '2017-03-18 01:30:00', '2017-03-18 04:00:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 3, '2017-03-18 01:45:00', '2017-03-18 03:00:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 4, '2017-03-18 02:10:00', '2017-03-18 02:30:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 5, '2017-03-18 02:35:00', '2017-03-18 02:50:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 6, '2017-03-18 03:20:00', '2017-03-18 03:50:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 7, '2017-03-18 05:00:00', '2017-03-18 05:30:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 8, '2017-03-18 05:10:00', '2017-03-18 07:00:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 9, '2017-03-18 05:50:00', '2017-03-18 08:00:00';


SELECT T1.Id, T1.StartDate, T1.EndDate FROM (
    SELECT *,
        LAG(EndDate) OVER(ORDER BY ID) as lagdate  ,
        LEAD(StartDate) OVER(ORDER BY ID) as leaddate  
    FROM #Dates) AS T1
WHERE T1.StartDate > T1.lagdate OR T1.lagdate IS NULL 
   OR T1.EndDate < T1.leaddate  OR T1.leaddate IS NULL
```

And this is the result:

[image]

*Note: `T1.lagdate IS NULL` is used to get the first row ,  `T1.leaddate IS NULL` is used to get the last one*

Comment: Sorry, but the solution does not work correctly. This task is more difficult than it seems. You solution show records with Id in (1, 5, 6, 7).

Comment: @IvanAntonov waiting for ur feedback :)

Comment: thank you very much for your help! But, this solution is suitable only for the current input data, if you change the input data a little, the solution produces an incorrect result:

Comment: With this data: 
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 1, '2017-03-18 04:00:00', '2017-03-18 10:30:00';
        INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 2, '2017-03-18 05:00:00', '2017-03-18 15:00:00';
        INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 3, '2017-03-18 07:00:00', '2017-03-18 20:00:00';
        INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 4, '2017-03-18 11:00:00', '2017-03-18 23:00:00';
        INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 5, '2017-03-18 12:30:00', '2017-03-18 19:00:00';

you solution select record with Ids IN (1, 5), but by logic should get records with Id 1 and 4

Comment: I made a working version and put it in the body of the question. If interested, you can look :)

Comment: @IvanAntonov happy that your issue is solved. Good luck

Comment: @IvanAntonov Post it as an answer and accept it. Dont post an answer in a question

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But, while I can not do this: "You can accept your own answer tomorrow" - I'll do it tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Dates (Id INT, StartDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME);
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 1, '2017-03-18 00:00:00', '2017-03-18 02:00:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 2, '2017-03-18 01:30:00', '2017-03-18 04:00:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 3, '2017-03-18 01:45:00', '2017-03-18 03:00:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 4, '2017-03-18 02:10:00', '2017-03-18 02:30:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 5, '2017-03-18 02:35:00', '2017-03-18 02:50:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 6, '2017-03-18 03:20:00', '2017-03-18 03:50:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 7, '2017-03-18 05:00:00', '2017-03-18 05:30:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 8, '2017-03-18 05:10:00', '2017-03-18 07:00:00';
INSERT INTO #Dates SELECT 9, '2017-03-18 05:50:00', '2017-03-18 08:00:00';

DECLARE  @Results TABLE (Id INT, StartDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME);

INSERT INTO @Results
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM #Dates
ORDER BY StartDate
```

/* This is the code for your filtration logic: After the first period of dates, we find another with which it does not intersect. Then the logic is repeated with respect to the found period. */

```
WHILE(@@ROWCOUNT > 0)   -- we did something the last insert
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @Results
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM #Dates d
    WHERE d.StartDate = 
        (SELECT MIN(StartDate)
        FROM #Dates
END 

SELECT *
FROM @Results
ORDER BY 1

DROP TABLE #Dates;

Id  StartDate               EndDate
1   2017-03-18 00:00:00.000 2017-03-18 02:00:00.000
4   2017-03-18 02:10:00.000 2017-03-18 02:30:00.000
5   2017-03-18 02:35:00.000 2017-03-18 02:50:00.000
6   2017-03-18 03:20:00.000 2017-03-18 03:50:00.000
7   2017-03-18 05:00:00.000 2017-03-18 05:30:00.000
9   2017-03-18 05:50:00.000 2017-03-18 08:00:00.000
```